# Unit testing Arduino (C++) code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, embedded, cross-compiling, arduino

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I unit test Arduino code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780819/how-can-i-unit-test-arduino-code)

What is the best way to have unit tests for embedded code? Specifically for Arduino. I'm writing a CNC controller, and I'd like to unit test my code for the motor control (that is, I know the sequence of output states, etc.). Is there a standard way of unit testing code for architectures other than the development machine?

Is the only way to compile for x_86 and run unit tests that way? Is that good enough? The `avr-gcc` compiler has very specific settings obviously. I'd like to test in the most relevant manner possible.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780819/how-can-i-unit-test-arduino-code

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see that. Looks like a pretty good source.