# Unit testing framework for ESP8266

Tags: c++, unit-testing, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

is there any way to unit test my classes written in c++ for ESP8266 Arduino platform? I really cannot find anything related material on the internet. I thought a widely used c++ unit testing library will work, but arduino is different as it has no try-catch blocks (thus exceptions) and other disadvantages compared to standard c++ etc etc.

What i need is simple: some assertion library, structuring capabilities (suites,test cases,...) and some kind of mocking and checking whether a method was called or not. 
Can anybody help?

Comment: i've not seen one, but you could write one for us. it's not as needed for arduino as in JS (where they are a huge deal) because the types tend to reduce runtime surprises.

Comment: That's what I am about to do. But I still need to get some c++ wisdom before doing it.

Comment: https://github.com/google/googletest

Answer (score 2):

I've just completed writing [a fairly extensive unit testing library called `arduino_ci`](https://github.com/Arduino-CI/arduino_ci), and I've placed a decent writeup [as an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49161903/2063546).

It doesn't offer the "was this method called" functionality you are asking for, but everything (including pin values and serial IO) is (or can be) mocked.

A few examples:

- The [DoSomething example library](https://github.com/Arduino-CI/arduino_ci/tree/master/SampleProjects/DoSomething) shown above, used to test arduino_ci itself
- A practical example, [testing a Queue implementation](https://github.com/sdesalas/Arduino-Queue.h/pull/1/files)
- A complex example, simulating a library that controls an interactive device over a SoftwareSerial connection as part of the [Adafruit FONA library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_FONA/pull/91/files)

Comment: Update: this is now available as a GitHub action https://github.com/marketplace/actions/arduino_ci